# Stem the word by using regex

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am trying to stem the words in the text by using regex.

```
c <- "Foo is down. No one wants Foos after this. Before, people liked Fooy a lot."
```

Desired output:

```
"Foo is down. No one wants Foo after this. Before, people liked Foo a lot."
```

I need to preserve the word `Foo`, but remove all the characters that follow in that word, keeping the rest of the string.

I managed to split the suffix from the base of the word, I can remove everything after variations of word "Foo", and I experimented with word boundaries, but cannot figure out how to get to the desired output.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: To elaborate on @CertainPerformance, I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that way we can help you out :)

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible regex to solve this replaces "Foo with one or more letters after it" with "Foo":

```
> x = "Foo is down. No one wants Foos after this. Before, people liked Fooy a lot."
> stringr::str_replace_all(x, "Foo[a-z]+", "Foo")
[1] "Foo is down. No one wants Foo after this. Before, people liked Foo a lot."
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `gsub` and replace the pattern `(?<=Foo)\S+` with empty string:

```
x <- "Foo is down. No one wants Foos after this. Before, people liked Fooy a lot."
output <- gsub("(?<=Foo)\\S+", "", x, perl=TRUE)
output

[1] "Foo is down. No one wants Foo after this. Before, people liked Foo a lot."
```

### Demo